# Change existing items in editable JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to implement editing of the combo items, e.g. when I select 3-th item "*Item 3*" and it appears in the input field, I alter the string to "*Item 3 new*" and press some button. I want 3-d item to have "*Item 3 new*" text.
Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write an [`ActionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) that replaces the selected element.
As a basis, see [*Using an Editable Combo Box*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#editable); the full example is in [`ComboBoxDemo2`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ComboBoxDemo2Project/src/components/ComboBoxDemo2.java).

Comment: Hm... So i have to replace current item each time the text in edit field is changed?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. The editable combo lets you to select a value from a set or give a custom value. It is not designed to replace select-items with the typed ones.